# Oracle Variable Definition

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I have an Oracle SQL package  that calls out a variable. The difficulty I'm finding is that I don't know where it's defined.

Here's an example:

```
select distinct policy_term_code, policy_term_history_pk, effective_from_date 
where policy_no = in_policy
from policy_term_history
```

I've searched the body of the entire package and I  cannot figure out where it's defined.

Comment: This is not valid SQL to start with. Why is the `from` clause *after* the `where` clause?

Comment: Might be a **function**, not a variable.

Comment: Did you look in the [PL/SQL] package specification? Or did you just look in the body?